# Laravel array loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have shipping method where will calculate price, this codes/prices etc. comes from third-party website (nothing stored in my database).

> my problem is i don't know how to get objects that i need!

here is screen shot of my data on `dd`

[image: screenshot1]

my `function`

```
public function index() {
        $province = RajaOngkir::Provinsi()->all();

       // this part will return dd image above
        $cost = RajaOngkir::Cost([
            'origin'        => 501, // id kota asal
            'destination'   => 114, // id kota tujuan
            'weight'        => 1000, // berat satuan gram
            'courier'       => 'jne', // kode kurir pengantar ( jne / tiki / pos )
        ])->get();
        return view('welcome', compact('province', 'cost'));
    }
```

my view codes `blade`

```
@foreach($cost as $option)
  {{$option['code']}} <br>
  {{$option['name']}}
@endforeach
```

PS: I got my `dd` with `{{dd($option)}}` in my loop(@foreach)

So far my loop return this (compare to dd to):

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: What exactly is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Jerodev good question :), I expect to get `service` name as radio buttons and `value` + `etd` in front of it so they users can choose from this carrier which service they want to product be sent with/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
  @if(!empty($cost))
    @foreach($cost as $option)
          {{$option['code']} <br>
          {{$option['name']}} <br>
           @if(!empty($option['costs']))
               @foreach($option['costs'] as $cost)
                     {{$cost['service']}} <br>
                     {{$cost['description']}} <br>
                     @if(!empty($cost['cost'])
                         @foreach($cost['cost'] as $c)
                             {{ $c['value'] }} <br>
                             {{ $c['etd'] }}  <br>     
                             {{ $c['note'] }}   <br>
                         @endforeach 
                     @endif            
              @endforeach
          @endif
    @endforeach
 @endif
```

Comment: @mafortis tell me what is the exact error that you get when you execute my code

Comment: as i said `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon..........................)`

Comment: Those are not objects, they are arrays so you need to use `$option['code']` etc.

Comment: Please refrain from using too much logic in the view. Prepare the variables before sending them to the view. So in index sanitize the values, then make a new array or collection, pass those to the blade. Ideally the blade should have no knowledge of the data structure of the data, just output it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 @foreach($cost as $option)
      {{$option['code']}} <br>
      {{$option['name'] }} <br>
       @foreach($option['costs'] as $cost)
            @foreach($cost as $arr)

             {{$arr['service'] }} <br>
             {{$arr['description']}} <br>
               @foreach($arr['cost'] as $c)
                    {{ $c['value'] }} <br>
                    {{ $c['etd'] }}  <br>     
                    {{ $c['note'] }}   <br>
              @endforeach
            @endforeach  

      @endforeach
@endforeach
```